I am trying to recreate this synthpunk sound
I am interested in how i could recreate the synth sound from this track. I am trying it through oxid(arp omni emulator) since it kinda reminds me of joy division, but so far even though i got close i cannnot get the sound just right. any reccomendation as to how could i achieve this sound, any free vsts that have this or can i achieve this through oxid.


 this is the sound in question.

Look up transistor combo organs to find the sound you're looking for.  Farfisa, Vox, Yamaha YC are some classic examples.

I'm not an organ expert by any means, so take all of this with a grain of salt. Or five.
Given the age of the track, genre, and where it was recorded, my gut feeling is that it would be some kind of organ or "clonewheel" organ.  I am not sure how many synthesizers would make it in the hands of erstwhile punkrockers in 1970s Yugoslavia.
I was able to find a live recording of them (same song even!) 

 but I can hardly make out what the keyboardist is using.  It seems like a Nord, but that doesn't really help us out much.
If you have access to an organ, or an organ-synth (or plugin) I'd start there. It sounds like a high pass filter (or at least, a low cut) is on the organ.  Definitely some vibrato on there!
Hopefully that helps a little.
